# Create a range of time in UiDatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have a problem with UiDatePicker.
I want to create a UiDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime mode.
My picker must have a range of hour but it haven't a range of day.

For example: the user can select always date form the picker, but can select the hour only in range 8.00 - 19.00.

Can you help me with a sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As you can easily see from the documentation, that's not possible with `UIDatePicker`. You would have to write you own date picker (by using `UIPickerView`).

Comment: +1 a reasonable idea, even if it is fiendishly difficult to write a date picker that's calendar-agnostic. :)

Answer (score 3):

`UIDatePicker` does not support this.  It *does* have `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` properties, but these do not give you the granularity to say "any day between 8am and 7pm".

What you could do instead is use 2 `UIDatePickers`.  The first one would be in `UIDatePickerModeDate` mode, and the second in `UIDatePickerModeTime` mode.  Use the first one to choose a day, and the second one to choose a time.  Once the user has chosen both, you could convert the 2 `NSDates` into `NSDateComponents` (using the `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`), and take the `-hour`, `-minute`, and `-second` from the second one, give it to the first, and then transform the first back into an `NSDate`.  (So basically combine the date information from the first `NSDate` with the time information from the second `NSDate`).

You should also [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) asking for this capability natively.